# How to check if device is an iPad or iPhone not working

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios-simulator

I am currently updating an app and I need to know whether the app is being used in an iPad or not.

I checked online and I found the code below. I used the iPad simulators in Xcode and ran both if statements. but whenever I run the code, nothing happens (the print message does not print) does this code work with simulators or am I doing something wrong?

When I check if it is UIUserInterfaceIdiom.phone the print statement executes, but I am using an iPad in the simulator.

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad){
        print("This is an iPad")
        redoButton.layer.position.y -= 500



    }

if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad{
        print("iPad True")
    }
```

Thank You

Comment: The second if statement should wrap within brackets I think. Eg. `if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad)`.

Comment: Is your app a Universal app? Are you using a Launch Screen storyboard?

Comment: @user7328702 No. Swift doesn't require parentheses.

Comment: FYI - you should not be making layout decisions based on device type. You should be making decisions based on view size.

Comment: @rmaddy no the app is made for iPhones. it is like that in the settings (Iphone

Comment: Do you now what is the maximum it can be for an iPhone ?

Comment: If it is an iPhone-only app then there's no need to check if it's an iPad or not since the app will run just like it's on an iPhone.

Comment: I thought this too but when I submitted my app in the App Store. It Got rejected because the images were messed up in the iPad View. They said it has to look good for an iPad aswell. Even if it is made for an iPhone

Comment: Hey. I when I change the Devices setting to Universal the code works. Is There any other way to check if the device is an iPad or not.

Comment: As I said, checking if it's an iPad or not is the wrong solution. Your app needs to work on iPhones of many different sizes. If you make your app a Universal app and fully support iPads too, then you use the same approach to dealing with different sized screens. Besides, on an iPad you should support multitasking which means your app's size can change while it is being run. This is why you need to based decisions on view size, not device type.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    print("iPad")
}else{
    print("not iPad")
}
```

But you need to make your app a universal app.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't *need* to make it a Universal app.  It is a good idea as it will give a better user experience for iPad owners, but all it *needs* to do is support 3.5" phones.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to frequently check iphone/ipad. use the following class

```
class Env {
  static var isIpad : Bool { return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad }
}
```

Then you can use like this

```
if Env.isIpad { // Ipad } 
else { iphone }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Sir @rmaddy. Its just an enhancement to accepted answer. If OP wants to check frequently. 

Should i remove it ?

Comment: Answers should first answer the question. Answers shouldn't just be a convenience of code in another answer. So yes, I would either delete your answer or update it to fully answer the question and provide information not found in other answers.

Comment: Yeah, but it's a cleaner solution regardless... I say leave it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
if UIDevice.current.model == "iPad" {
        
}
```